# How to correctly import certificate in Java keystore with keytool? What is wrong in this statment?

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, jsse

I have some problem trying to import a certificate into the Java certificate.

I try to perform this statment:

```
keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias ALIASNAME -file C:/Users/nobil/OneDrive/Documenti/mycompany/test/52708968.crt -keystore C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/securitycacerts -storepass changeit
```

But I am obtaining this error message:

```
nobil@DESKTOP-VCON7T6 MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security
$ keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias ALIASNAME -file C:/Users/nobil/OneDrive/Documenti/mycompany/test/52708968.crt -keystore C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/securitycacerts -storepass changeit
Opzione non valida:  Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/securitycacerts
keytool -importcert [OPTION]...

Importa un certificato o una catena di certificati

Opzioni:

 -noprompt                       non richiedere
 -trustcacerts                   considera sicuri i certificati da cacerts
 -protected                      password mediante meccanismo protetto
 -alias <alias>                  nome alias della voce da elaborare
 -file <filename>                nome file di input
 -keypass <arg>                  password chiave
 -keystore <keystore>            nome keystore
 -storepass <arg>                password keystore
 -storetype <storetype>          tipo keystore
 -providername <providername>    nome provider
 -providerclass <providerclass>  nome classe provider
 -providerarg <arg>              argomento provider
 -providerpath <pathlist>        classpath provider
 -v                              output descrittivo

Utilizzare "keytool -help" per visualizzare tutti i comandi disponibili
```

Why? What is wrong?

Comment: [Installing Trusted Certificates into a Java Keystore](https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/installing_trusted_certificates_into_a) form the Oracle blogs, plus all the other hits on the web.

Comment: You need to quote `"Program Files"`. Another thing that is wrong is `securitycacerts`. Should be `security/cacerts`. Another thing that is wrong is that you should not modify this file.

Comment: @EJP Please can you show me how to quote the "Program Files"? Can you write me the string that I have to perform in my shell? Tnx

Comment: I have *already* shown you.

Comment: keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias ALIASNAME -file "C:/Users/nobil/OneDrive/Documenti/mycompany/test/52708968.crt" -keystore "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -storepass changeit

Comment: You should never modify the keystores shipped with Java. When you update your JRE or JDK they are gone. Always use separate keystore files.